# Samsung Galaxy 10.1 2013 frozen in odin mode

Tags: odin

Granddaughter playing game on tablet and assume she pressed on power and volume at same time It had the Samsung Galaxy 10.1 verbiage across the screen. I tried to press the power and increase volume button as I had done before on the Motorola Xoom, big mistake from what I read in forums. It is now stuck on the ODIN MODE and says: Downloading...Do not turn off target!! with the Android symbol above it. Help!!

Answer (score 2):

Hold the <kbd>volume up</kbd> and <kbd>volume down</kbd> at the same time then press <kbd>power</kbd> button. Hold for a few seconds and unit will reboot.

Answer (score 0):

This warning is only meant for people to not turn off the device during the flashing process.  If you did not start flashing an image to this tables, and don't plan to - it's perfectly safe to power off the tablet.

Holding the <kbd>Power</kbd> button for around 10 seconds should cause the tablet to turn off.  You can then turn it on normally again, without touching the Volume buttons.